# Applications changing the language at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, multilingual

I have read the tutorials about how to make a multilingual program in .Net, and it works well, but here I need an idea to make all the things at run-time easier.
At run-time when the user click on the language. I change the culture to the proper language chosen for example:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en");
```

and then calling a function which set the Text for the layout of my form:

```
private System.Resources.ResourceManager rm;
fileToolStripMenuItem1.Text =  rm.GetString("fileToolStripMenuItem1.Text");
settingsToolStripMenuItem.Text = rm.GetString("settingsToolStripMenuItem.Text");
```

As it seems the look-up table which has been built by .Net when I set the text for each component of my program is equals to the property which should be set into it. In other word, the "fileToolStripMenuItem1.Text" is passing to the GetString() function and the result should be set to fileToolStripMenuItem1.Text, so I don't know how can I do it or even with which tool it is possible to iterate on every property of the rm and then by reflection or something else assign the value of the key to the key. That is to say, suppose "fileToolStripMenuItem1.Text" is the key in the lookup table and the value is "A" so how can I do this: Assigning the value of "fileToolStripMenuItem1.Text" which is "A" to fileToolStripMenuItem1.Text

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the culture of a WinForms application at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556367/how-do-i-change-the-culture-of-a-winforms-application-at-runtime)

Comment: I have faced another problem I have changed the subItems of menustrip but in your function ApplyResources it iterates on the menuStrip and skip the subItems!

Answer (score 0):

I've written some test winforms app and try it and can change controls Text property dynamicly fine. You can extend this solution if need.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    //main logic of switching language of UI
    void ChangeCulture_Handler(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //getting relative path of resource file for specific culture
        var resourcePath = GetLocalizedResourceFile(culture);
        //initialize new reader of resource file
        var reader = new ResXResourceReader(resourcePath);
        //getting enumerator
        var resourceEnumerator = reader.GetEnumerator();
        //enumerate each record in resource file
        while (resourceEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            string resKey = Convert.ToString(resourceEnumerator.Key);
            //we can add here some check if need 
            //(for example if in resource file exists not only controls resources with format <Control Name>.<Property>
            //if( resKey.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length == 2) 
            string resValue = Convert.ToString(resourceEnumerator.Value);
            //actually update property
            UpdateControl(resKey, resValue);
        }
    }

    //main logic of updating property of one control
    private void UpdateControl(string resKey, string resValue)
    {
        //we suppose that format of keys in resource file is <Control Name>.<Property>
        var strs = resKey.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var controlName = strs[0];
        var controlProp = strs[1];

        //find control of form by its name
        var controls = this.Controls.Find(controlName, true);
        if (controls.Length > 0)
        {
            //select first control
            var control = controls[0];
            //getting type of it
            var t = control.GetType();
            //getting property
            var props = t.GetProperty(controlProp);
            if (props != null)
            {
                //setting localized value to property
                props.SetValue(control, resValue, null);
            }
        }
    }

    //build resource file path
    string GetLocalizedResourceFile(CultureInfo ci)
    {
        string cultureCode = ci.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        //for english language is default, so we don't have a need to add "en" part in path 
        return cultureCode != "en" ? string.Format("Resource1.{0}.resx", cultureCode) : "Resource1.resx";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es-MX");
        ChangeCulture_Handler(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        ChangeCulture_Handler(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

}

Resource for english (Resource1.resx)

```
button1.Text    Change language to es   
button2.Text    Change language to en   
label1.Text         label1  
label2.Text         label2
```

Resource for spanish (Resource1.es.resx)

```
button1.Text    cambiar el idioma to es 
button2.Text    cambiar el idioma to en 
label1.Text     lalble1 
label2.Text     lalble2
```