# TableLayoutPanel resizing on change to CultureInfo

Tags: c#

I am busy building a login form that allows the user to choose their preferred language. When the language is changed in the dropdown, then all the controls are intended to match the new language. This bit works well.

The unexpected behaviour is that after changing to French then back to English, the size of the columns in the TableLayoutPanel change. This change is happening as part of the call to `Apply Resources` in the `LocalizedForm.cs` class.

There doesn't appear to be any similar issues on StackOverflow, or found via a Google search.

The code for the project is in my [glowing-tribble Github repository](https://github.com/nstoker/glowing-tribble).

The English (default) layout:
[image: The expected image layout]

The French translation layout:
[image]

Re-selecting the English translation and the unexpected and undesired change to the positioning of the TableLayoutPanel. 
[image: The unexpected change in layout]

The form localization code was found [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711426/proper-way-to-change-language-at-runtime)

I have been going round in circles with this issue for more time than I care to admit.

Comment: It appears that the column size settings are being cleared *sometimes* when a culture change is being imposed. But not always.

I have a work around in play, but aren't totally happy with having to do this.

Comment: It also appears that a number of labels and text boxes are also being resized - back to tracking down an answer.

Comment: did you somehow solve this issue? I am pretty interested in your workaround.

Comment: No, we ended up dropping the project.