# How can i change my winform to another language

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have a winform and i changed the language of the form to Dutch. After that i edit the name of the groupboxes labels etc. The moment i change a radiobutton do Dutch it only changes the namess of the groupboxes and not the labels en textboxes.

I changed the language of my form to Dutch. Then i made 2 Radiobuttons Dutch and German. the moment i press Dutch language radiobutton it only changes the name of the groupboxes and the other labels and stuff stay the same.

This is the methode and code i used.

```
  private void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
        {
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
                resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
            }
        }

 private void DutchRadiobutton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeLanguage("nl-NL");

        }
```

I want the whole form to change and every control in it when i click the radiobutton dutch language. For now only the groupbox names changes but the labels and textboxes in it stay the same langauge.

Comment: You need to recursively loop through the controls, otherwise you don't apply the changes to the inner controls of the GroupBox(es).

Comment: @Odrai how do i do that angel ?

Comment: Please have a look at [C# Recursion](https://www.dotnetperls.com/recursion)

Answer (score 0):

**Recursion example**

The input of this method could be 'this', which is e.g. a reference of your control or GroupBox.

```
private void ApplyChanges(Control ctrl)
{
    foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        // Do something

        Debug.WriteLine($"ctrl name: {c.Name}"); // Test code, just to print the control name(s).
        if (c.Controls != null && c.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            ApplyChanges(ctrl);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Language change method**

```
private void ApplyResources(Control parent, CultureInfo culture)
{
    _componentResourceManager.ApplyResources(parent, parent.Name, culture);

    foreach (Control ctl in parent.Controls)
    {
        ApplyResources(ctl, culture);
    }
}
```

Or have a look at the existing question/answer: ['Proper way to change language at runtime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711426/proper-way-to-change-language-at-runtime)

Comment: Moet dit in de andere methode of moet ik dit apparat toevoegen ben nieuw in het programmeren

Comment: @Merve Please write your comments in English so all StackOverflow users are able to follow the discussion. Nevertheless, I've updated my post.