# how to change the language dynamically of a form

Tags: .net, winforms, localization, globalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the culture of a WinForms application at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556367/how-do-i-change-the-culture-of-a-winforms-application-at-runtime)

I am using an xml file as a language property file with lang_en & lang_de, reading from the 'name' 'value' pair,but how on clicking ok button the form should change dynamically.?
I am using a dropdown list to select the language.

Comment: i have not used any resource(.resx) files to change the culture.

Comment: Then you should use resources as a starting point to use multiple cultures

Comment: I am able to change the language now, but its happening only after restarting the application, but not dynamically...

Comment: try to change the culture, `Thread.CurrentThread.Culture`, and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`